# Change MongoDB sizeOnDisk when i create a new database

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, nosql

I used PHP to create MongoDB database. My problem is that every time I create a database, the database's "size on disk" is some 200MB. I want to reduce it down to 25-50MB every time.

I have tried to use "command" and look in the `.conf` file for MongoDB without luck.

I run CentOS 6.2 if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run the command `mongod --help` you will see various options you can add when you start-up MongoDB.   Two you may want to research are:

```
  --noprealloc                disable data file preallocation - will often hurt
                              performance
  --smallfiles                use a smaller default file size
```

Comment: i use smallfiles right now and its start on 64mb filesize, can i make it lower to like 32mb? - how hurt are noprealloc?

Comment: noprealloc means files will be allocated only when you actually need them, not ahead of time.  try it to see how much it affects your performance, if at all.

Comment: Okay nice, the MongoDB its only use for "read" like 95% of the time and 5% wirte, so i think i will try to disalbe noprealloc :)